# Making a Cash Register on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm trying to make a store program on Python 3.6 and my code's not working.I made a lot of revisions, now I'm encountering more internal coding problems such as making the menu run in a loop until the customer exits the program and creating lists inside of lists with all of the information of the respective items. Code may not appear indented correctly here but that's more a copy and pasting error.

Here's the code:

```
class RetailItem:
    def __init__(self):
        self.price = price
        self.units = units
        self.description = description


class CashRegister:
    def __init__(RetailItem, self):
        self.totalprice=0
        self.cart=[]
        self.items=[]
        duck = RetailItem
        duck.description = "Large plush duck"
        duck.units = 3
        duck.price = 6.99

        porcupine = RetailItem
        porcupine.description = "Pink plush porcupine"
        porcupine.units = 5
        porcupine.price = 9.99

        bunny = RetailItem
        bunny.description = "small white plush bunny"
        bunny.units = 7
        bunny.price = 4.99

        self.items=[duck,bunny,porcupine]
        print("Welcome to The Toy Store.\n Selection:\n 1.Duck \n 2.Bunny \n 3.Porcupine")
    def menu(self):
        item = int(input("What would you like to select? "))
        item=+1
        item = self.items[item]
        return item
    def purchase(RetailItem):
        self.items = self.items.append(item)
        self.totalprice = totalprice.append(item.price)
        item.units=item.units-1
        self.cart= self.items.append(item)
        print("You have added"+(item)+"to your cart")
    def get_total(self):
        return("Your total is", self.totalprice)
    def show_item(RetailItem):    
        return(description(RetailItem), units(RetailItem), price(RetailItem))
    def clear_register(self):
        self.totalprice = []
        self.items = []
```

def main():

```
C1=CashRegister(CashRegister)

C1.menu()

choice=int(input(("Options: \n 1.Add to Cart 2. View item \n 3.Return to Main Menu ")))
if choice==1:
    purchase(item)
if choice==2:
    show_item(item)
    choice=int(input(("Would you like to purchase this item? \n 1. Yes \n 2. No"))
if choice==3:
    C1.menu()
choice=int(input(("Options: \n 1. Add more items to your cart. 2.View cart 3. Quit"))
if choice!= 3:
    if choice==1:
           menu()
```

Comment: Which inputs did you provide that caused `main is not defined` error?

Comment: Unfortunately, your code have serious issues.

Comment: By the way, only classes should be capitalized, not left hand variable names or parameters

Comment: I'm not sure how to run your code. Do I put the code that was in main simply in the top level? I also don't understand the purpose of the str function over python's on inbuilt str conversion.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though `def menu(self)` is not inside any class, so it shouldn't have a `self` parameter. Remove it, and it should work. Or put `menu` into a class.

The `self` parameter is reserved for class methods. More info [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#method-objects)

EDIT: Actually, if I understand your code, your `menu(self)` belongs to the `CashRegister` class. If so, just indent the entire `menu(self)` block.

```
class CashRegister:
    def __int__(self,RetailItem):
        self.total= ()
        Duck = RetailItem()
        Duck.description = "Large plush duck"
        Duck.units = 3
        Duck.price = 6.99

        Porcupine = RetailItem()
        Porcupine.description = "Pink plush porcupine"
        Porcupine.units = 5
        Porcupine.price = 9.99

        Bunny = RetailItem()
        Bunny.description = "small white plush bunny"
        Bunny.unitsininv = 7
        Bunny.price = 4.99

    def menu(self):
        print("Welcome to The Toy Store.\n Selection:\n 1.Bunny \n 2.Porcupine \n 3.Duck")
        choice = int(input("What would you like to buy? "))
        if choice==1:
            item = Bunny
        elif choice == 2:
            item = Porcupine
        elif choice==3:
            item = Duck
        else:
            print("Error")
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I had menu indented it just misprinted here. Unfortunately I'm still getting the "menu is not defined" error when running this code.

Comment: You're probably getting the error on the line ```if choice==1: menu()```, and there the menu really is undefined. ```menu``` is ```CashRegister```'s method, so you need to call it on an instance of ```CashRegister```, in your case ```C1```.

Answer (score 1):

**How to deal with** `menu not defined`**:**

- Keyword `self` is used for **methods inside classes**. `menu` is a
  **method** at top level.

  Just indent `menu` so it becomes a method of class `CashRegister`.

**There are also other issues with your program.**

- You forgot to indent the Porcupine and Bunny objects so it will be in the `__init__` of `CashRegister`
- Your inputting with `choice` does not work.
- Your `CashRegister C1` isn't correctly initiated. You need to initialize it as an *object*: `C1 = CashRegister(*some RetailObject*`) not `C1 = CashRegister`
- `Bunny.unitsininv`: `unitsininv` doesn't exist as a `RetailItem` field.
- `total` for `CashRegister` should be a list.
- `purchase`, `get_total`, `show_items`, `clear_register` should also be methods of `CashRegister` with a `self`.
- There is a typo for init: you typed `__int__` instead

Here is the updated code, you can take time to read to understand what you need to set up your CashRegister, and you can just use the Python Shell to make purchases to your CashRegister.

```
class RetailItem:
    def __init__(self, price, units, description): 
        self.price = price
        self.units = units
        self.description = description

    def __str__(self):
        string = str(self.description)
        string += ": $" + str(self.price)
        string += " Units:" + str(self.units)
        return string


class CashRegister:
    def __init__(self):
        self.total_items = [] # Should be a List
        self.total_price = 0; # Missing

    def menu(self):
        print("Welcome to The Toy Store.\n Selection:\n 1.Bunny \n 2.Porcupine \n 3.Duck")
        choice = int(input("What would you like to buy? "))
        if choice==1:
            item = Bunny
        elif choice == 2:
            item = Porcupine
        elif choice==3:
            item = Duck
        else:
            print("Error")

    def purchase(self, item: RetailItem):
        self.total_items.append(item.description)
        self.total_price += item.price

    def get_total(self):
        print("Your total items are: ", self.total_items)

    def show_items(self):    
        print("Your total price is: ", self.total_price)

    def clear_register():
        total_price = []
        total_items = 0
```